# Order array with rows

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I try to sort array of rows using the array_sort function, but not result as I wanted.

the first result order correctly

```
[{type=CALM, confidence=95.1536636352539}, {type=CONFUSED, confidence=1.1397864818572998}, {type=HAPPY, confidence=0.07988717406988144}, {type=SAD, confidence=1.7613277435302734}, {type=SURPRISED, confidence=0.3601384460926056}]
```

the second line return another result

```
[{type=CALM, confidence=0.5053133368492126}, {type=CONFUSED, confidence=0.4852835536003113}, {type=HAPPY, confidence=92.1430892944336}, {type=SAD, confidence=1.6924850940704346}, {type=SURPRISED, confidence=3.10842227935791}]
```

The result expected to second line is

```
[
{type=HAPPY, confidence=92.1430892944336},
{type=SURPRISED, confidence=3.10842227935791},
{type=SAD, confidence=1.6924850940704346},
{type=CALM, confidence=0.5053133368492126},
{type=CONFUSED, confidence=0.4852835536003113}]
```

It's possible sort by confidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer Presto version, you can use [`array_sort`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_sort) function that takes a lambda function (like sorting in Java with a comparator):

```
SELECT array_sort(array_or_rows,
    (a, b) -> IF(a[2] < b[2], 1, IF(a[2] = b[2], 0, -1))
...
```

However, Athena [is based](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html) in [Presto 0.172](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/), so this `array_sort` variant [is not available](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html) and you need to do something like this instead:

1. swap sides of your `ROW` type so that `confidence` is first
2. sort array
3. swap `ROW`s back

E.g.:

```
SELECT
  transform(
    array_sort(
      transform(
        array_or_rows,
        r -> CAST(r AS ROW(confidence double, type varchar)))),
    r -> CAST(r AS ROW(type varchar, confidence double)))
....
```